# Creating a medieval fireball thrower weapon?

Tags: internal-consistency, technology, weapons, medieval, tactics

I want to create a medium-distance personal weapon that hurls fireballs with medieval technology for light infantry against heavy infantry. It needs to be similar like a crossbow. Is it possible to create this weapon with medieval technology?

Comment: What's wrong with fire tipped arrows? For the time being I've VTC'd as too broad as you haven't defined the requirements of your weapon well enough. "Fireball"? What do you count as a fireball? From who's perspective? From the person who's getting shot, whether it's a ball of pure plasma, a piece of flaming poop, or a fire tipped arrow, all they'll see is a "ball" of fire. And that isn't the only thing that needs to be defined. What is "medium distance"? "Medieval technology" spanned several centuries with quite a large difference in technological improvements. What's the tech level really at?

Comment: Similar to a crossbow how? Shape, size, weight, material, construction style, firing mechanism? All of the above? There were also different types of crossbows back then.

Comment: Weapon design works better when you work backward from the intended effect. What's the *purpose* of the fireball? Burn soldiers? Disrupt cavalry? Damage fortifications? Ignite the target? Remember that fuel, if needed for fireballs, can be heavy, expensive, hard to transport safely, and sometimes poisonous.

Comment: I disagree with @Aify that this is too broad.  I completely agree with Aify that this is unclear (I'm going to VTH as unclear).  I'm happy to retract my VTH once the question is clarified.  "Fireball" can mean fire-tipped-arrow, ball-of-flaming-goo (catapult), magical-fireball (wand), etc.  All have a purpose, so user535733 is also correct.  We could use knowing what you want to do with it.  Thanks.

Comment: [Greek fire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_fire)? It's medieval, it's incendiary, it's terrifying...

Comment: I did not vote to close. The comment about Greek fire (the Greeks in question called themselves Romans and inhabited the medieval Eastern Roman/Byzantine Empire) was intended as an example of a similar (but larger) weapon in real history. And while the *exact* recipe  is unknown, we know what it was, how it was used, and we could easily duplicate the weapon.

Comment: Actually, @AlexP's answer was clever and worth thinking about.  We're closing because you've been unclear.  It isn't arrogant, it's part of the process.  Without the VTH/VTC process you could (and often would) get a lot of low quality answers because we're guessing about what you want.  We're ready to both retract the votes and answer the question.  We just need you to clarify what you want.

Comment: About Greek Fire, I remember reading a few decades ago about one experiment trying to duplicate the formula that produce moving fireballs or at least it sort of spat out globs of burning material without any mechanism to throw it.  So looking up all previous Greek Fire experiments should lead you to that attempt and you might be able to base your weapon on a superior version. 
 WARNING many incendiary products have been sold under the name of Greek Fire in recent centuries but don't use the actual medieval Greek Fire whose formula is unknown.

Answer (score 2):

Forget actual fireballs unless you have artillery.

Frankly, fire arrows are not that good, but since you mentioned crossbows, repeating crossbows might do the trick, as they do not have the same velocity. Realistically, the arrows still would have a large chance of failure to ignite what they hit (even if it's wood / dry hay).

Maybe some sort of Molotov Cocktail using crude oil / napatha and ceramics flung by a sling. It would be expensive and limited to certain areas, but it should be a valid substitute for a true fireball.

Answer (score 0):

[Greek fire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_fire) seems like the best choice, also because cannot be extinguished with water.

Dip a projectile into it and use a slingshot to launch it against enemies.

Even better, if you seal it into a small pot, it will crash and then set on fire, so you will add a surprise effect on the enemy: they won't see fire coming on them, they will see fire after the impact. And panic is a useful ally during a battle.